# Derivation for Quantum optics dipole radiation formula

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, radiation, quantum-optics, dipole

An often used formula for the radiation field of a dipole is the following one:

\begin{align}
\vec{E}(t, \vec{x}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi x^3} ( 3 \hat{x} [ \hat{x} \vec{d}(t_r)] - \vec{d}(t_r) ) + \frac{1}{4 \pi x^2} ( 3 \hat{x} [ \hat{x} \dot{\vec{d}}(t_r)] - \dot{\vec{d}}(t_r) ) + \frac{1}{4 \pi x^3} (\hat{x}\times [\hat{x} \times \ddot{\vec{d}}(t_r)])
\end{align}
Where the hats indicate unit vectors, $t_r$ is the retarded time, and $E$ and $d$ constitute operators.
In this case it is taken from equation 3,  [Citation Adam Stokes 2016 Eur. J. Phys. 37 034001 DOI 10.1088/0143-0807/37/3/034001](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/37/3/034001)

A similar formula, although for classical electrodynamics, can be found in John David Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics, 3rd ed. (Wiley, 1999), p. 411.

Now my question is: Can the above formula be derived in the frame work of quantum optics (for example in dipole approximation:)
\begin{align}
H_0 = \sum_{\vec{k}} \hbar \omega_{\vec{k}} a_{\vec{k}}^{\dagger} a_{\vec{k}} + H_{0 \text{Atom}}
\end{align}
And
\begin{align}
H_{int} = \vec{d} \vec{E}(t, 0)
\end{align}

The cited paper does not give a source for the given formula. Is there a book / paper that gives a derivation? The proof one finds in the jackson book can't be used, because it relies on the classical maxwell equations, where as in our case I would have to relie on the heisenberg equations of motion for the given hamiltonian.

Comment: Maxwell's equation are still used in quantum optics and in quantum field theory. One just needs to be careful with the interaction term.

Comment: @flippiefanus what do you mean by "be careful" - is there literature on that?

Comment: In Maxwell's equations, the interaction terms are just source terms. In QED, they are couplings with the fermion (e.g. electron) fields that are dynamic fields in their own right. Without these couplings, QED reproduces the source-free Maxwell equations.

Comment: @flippiefanus without interactions, the Heisenberg equations for the electric field yield the Maxwell equations without sources ( and this is consistent with the solutions being expandable in plane waves). But for the interacting case with an electron ( in some suitable  approximation where it can be described by a single wave function), is there still an interacting version of Maxwell's equations?

Comment: Yes, then the electron is represented by charges and currents in Maxwell's equations.